# Function to return value from "chopped" input range

Tags: algorithm, interpolation

I'm looking for a function or algorithm that, for a value in a specified range, will return a value in the same range but based on the chop/divide the value is in. Difficult to explain - some expected output based on this empty shell

```
function choppedRange(value, min, max, chops) {
    // value - a value in range min to max
    // chops - integer defining how many "subranges" or "chops" to return values from
    ...
}

// Map (linear conversion) input value in range oldMin -> oldMax
// to a value in range newMin -> newMax
function remap(oldValue, oldMin, oldMax, newMin, newMax) {
    return (((oldValue - oldMin) * (newMax - newMin)) / (oldMax - oldMin)) + newMin;
}
```

[image: Illustration]
What the illustration is trying to show is the following:

1. Determine in which chop the input value (blue dot) is. (let's say it's  value is `0.35`...)
2. Remap (function above) the value (blue) `0.35` in range `0,25` to `0.5`
   to be in the range of `min` and `max` arguments e.g. `0` to `1`: `remap(0.35, 0.25, 0.5, 0, 1)`
3. The output (green dot) with the example values should be `0.3999...`

Hope you can see what I mean.

As you can see I have the remapping done - but I'm having trouble deciding the "chop" values for the input to `remap` - like this:

```
remap(input_value, chop_min, chop_max, min, max)
```

I want to find `chop_min` and `chop_max` based on the `chops` argument in `choppedRange`

```
function choppedRange(value, min, max, chops) {
    // Figure out chop_min and chop_max
    ...
    return remap(value, chop_min, chop_max, min, max)
}
```

Comment: It's quite difficult to figure out what you're after, are we talking about rounding here?

Comment: Yeah - sorry about that - I've tried to update with an illustration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this implementation

```js
function choppedRange(value, min, max, chops) {
  // value - a value in range min to max
  // chops - integer defining how many "subranges" or "chops" to return values from
  var chopMin = min, chopMax = max, chopValue = max / chops, i, c
  for (i = 1; i <= chops; i++) {
    c = chopValue * i
    if (c < value)
      chopMin = c
    if (c >= value) {
      chopMax = c
      break;
    }
  }
  return (((value - chopMin) * (max - min)) / (chopMax - chopMin)) + min
}

var r = choppedRange(0, 0, 1, 4)
console.log('Result',r)
r = choppedRange(0.35, 0, 1, 4)
console.log('Result',r)
r = choppedRange(0.5, 0, 1, 4)
console.log('Result',r)
r = choppedRange(0.6, 0, 1, 4)
console.log('Result',r)
r = choppedRange(1, 0, 1, 4)
console.log('Result',r)
```